# How can I access variables from other classes in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, variables, .net-4.0

I'm a beginning programmer, and I need to know how to access and edit variables for another class. This is some example code I have

---

```
Public Class class1
    Dim strName, strAge, strGender As String

Public Class class2
    / I need to edit the variables in this class. How do I do this?
```

Comment: Which instance of the class?

Comment: The whole point of classes is that some vars are private and managed entirely by the class.  Those which are useful to others are exposed thru properties

Comment: Your variables  should be declared with an access level of "Public", then  you use the fully qualified name to access the variable: MyClassInstace.MyVariableName = whatever

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a property that exposes the variable:

```
Dim ThisClassVariable as String

Public Property ClassVariable as String
    Get 
      Return ThisClassVariable
    End Get 
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
      ThisClassVariable = value
    End Set 
End Property
```

Then when you create an instance of the class named "foo" you access the variable by using `foo.ClassVariable`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8ae41a4.aspx