# VB NET list of in a class doesnt return anything

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a class with some variables and one of the is List(of integer).
I wont put the whole code because it is large only the list in the class.

```
    Dim excluir As New List(Of Integer)

Public Sub New(taquilla As Integer, gallera As String, libras As Integer, onzas As Integer, puya As Integer, tuerto As Boolean, puntos As Integer, excluir As List(Of Integer))
    Me.taquilla = taquilla
    Me.gallera = gallera
    Me.libras = libras
    Me.onzas = onzas
    Me.puya = puya
    Me.tuerto = tuerto
    Me.excluir = excluir
    Me.puntos = puntos
End Sub
Public Property excluirP As List(Of Integer)
    Get
        Return excluir
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of Integer))
        excluir = value
    End Set
End Property
```

In my form i add values to the list "excluir"

```
Dim excluir As New List(Of Integer)

Dim x As Integer
 Do
   x = InputBox("Mete un numero o presiona enter para finalizar")
   excluir.Add(x)

 Loop Until excluir.Count = 3
```

Then add the values to the object

```
misGallos.Add(New Gallo(txtTaquilla.Text, txtGallera.Text, txtLibras.Text, txtOnzas.Text, txtPuya.Text, tuerto, txtPuntos.Text, excluir))
```

The problem when i tried to print the values of that list in the object it doesnt return anything.

```
    For i = 0 To excluir.Count
        For j = 0 To excluir.Count
            MsgBox(misGallos(i).excluirP.Item(j))
        Next
    Next
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access variables from other classes in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977676/how-can-i-access-variables-from-other-classes-in-vb-net)

Comment: _"In my form i add values to the list "excluir""_ -- actually, no you don't. When in your form you have the declaration `Dim excluir As New List(Of Integer)` you've created a whole new instance of the list, completely separate from the one in the other class. See proposed duplicate for one way to share the list between the two classes. Please note that there may be other, much more appropriate ways, depending on what your full code actually looks like. Frankly, explaining all of the possibilities would make the question too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this in very much the wrong way.  When you expose a collection via a property, while you don't necessarily have to, you generally should make the property read-only.  By doing so, you enable items to be added, removed and accessed, but you don't allow the list itself to be replaced or, worse still, removed and not replaced.  E.g.

```
Public Class SomeType

    Public ReadOnly Property Numbers As New List(Of Integer)

    '...

End Class
```

If you want to be able to populate the list using a constructor then you can do so, but you don't set the property itself.  You get the property and then add items to it, e.g.

```
Public Class SomeType

    Public ReadOnly Property Numbers As New List(Of Integer)

    Public Sub New(numbers As IEnumerable(Of Integer))
        Me.Numbers.AddRange(numbers)
    End Sub

    '...

End Class
```

As for your issue, your loops don't make sense.  This:

```
For i = 0 To excluir.Count
    For j = 0 To excluir.Count
        MsgBox(misGallos(i).excluirP.Item(j))
    Next
Next
```

ought to at least be this:

```
For i = 0 To misGallos.Count - 1
    For j = 0 To misGallos(i).excluirP.Count - 1
        MessageBox.Show(misGallos(i).excluirP(j).ToString())
    Next
Next
```

Note that in the upper bounds must be 1 less than the count.  Also note that, if you're using `i` to index `misGallos` then the upper bound of the outer loop should be based on the count of `misGallos` rather than `excluirP`.  Most importantly, note that the inner loop is based on the current item indicated by the outer loop, not something else entirely.

Better still would be to use `For Each` loops rather than `For` loops.  If you are using a `For` loop counter to do nothing other than index a single list, you should almost certainly be using a `For Each` loop instead.

```
For Each m In misGallos
    For Each e In m.excluirP
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString())
    Next
Next
```

Again, note that the inner loop is based on the current item from the outer loop.

Also, please use upper-case letters to start the names of properties.

Comment: @Craig, indeed I did. Correction made.